# Rendering a React component in a Jest test returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, undefined

I have been trying to create a test with React, with the component TodoItems. It is just a regular Todolist with some basic features. When the test runs, it gives an error saying todos is undefined. The code in the test itself doesn't work as a result.

Test:

```
it("Tasks length increased by one when task is added.", () => {
  const { todos } = render(<TodoItems />);
  const todoLen = getByTestId(todos, "tasks");

  console.log(todos);
  expect(todoLen.toBe(1));
});
```

Component tested:

```
export default function Tasks() {
  let [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      content: "(Dette er en eksempelopppgave) "
    }
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/all", {
      crossDomain: true,
      method: "GET",
      mode: "no-cors",
      credentials: "include"
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("TodoItems is fetching.. ", response);
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.log("Fetching failed, response status: " + response.status);
          return;
        }
        response.json().then(function(data) {
          //was data instead of tasks, testing
          console.log(data, " is a response");
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Fetch error: ", err);
      });
  }, []);

  // });

  let handleAddTask = task => {
    setTasks(tasks.concat(task));
    console.log("handleAddTask content: " + JSON.stringify(task));
  };

  let handleDeleteTask = id => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter(task => task.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="Tasks">
      <h2>Tasks</h2>
      <TaskList deleteTask={handleDeleteTask} tasks={tasks} />
      <TaskForm addTask={handleAddTask} />
      <Button onClick={reqListener}>Load</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit(complete test code):

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import TodoItems from "../components/TodoItems.js";
import { render, fireEvent, getByTestId } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "../App.js";

//Test for the tasks array.
it("Tasks length increased by one when task is added.", () => {
  const { container, getByTestId } = render(<TodoItems />);
  const todos = getByTestId("tasks");

  expect(container).toBeDefined();
  expect(todos).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Comment: You're rendering `TodoItems` but exported component's name is `Tasks`?

Comment: I thought when rendering TodoItems, it would automatically assume Tasks() was what we wanted?

Comment: Depends how you import it into your test file, also what framework are you using for rendering?

Comment: I am using this: 
import { render, fireEvent, getByTestId } from "@testing-library/react"; 
and
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

renderer is not in use however

Answer (score 1):

When you're testing with the `@testing-library/react`, the `render` method returns `container` with a bunch of helpful getters, so you can do as follows:

```
it("Tasks length increased by one when task is added.", () => {
  const { container, getByTestId } = render(<TodoItems />);
  const todos = getByTestId("tasks"); 

  expect(container).toBeDefined();
  expect(todos).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

For the line `const todos = getByTestId("tasks");` to work, you need to add `data-testid` attribute to your component:

```
 <TaskList deleteTask={handleDeleteTask} tasks={tasks} data-testid="tasks"/>
```

Comment: I copied your code, and added the line in <TaskList>, but I get an error in the test: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="tasks"]